# uncaught typeerror: object function has no method 'tojson'

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have created a model like this

```
define(['backbone', 'text_dictionary'], function(Backbone, Text_Dict) {
var IndexPageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        val_btn_gotohomepage : Text_Dict.val_btn_gotohomepage,
        val_btn_gotologinpage : Text_Dict.val_btn_gotologinpage,
        val_btn_gotolistpage : Text_Dict.val_btn_gotolistpage
    }
});
return IndexPageModel;
});
```

and instantiated this model with 'new' in my page code like this

```
define([ 'page_layout', 
     'panel_itemview',
     'header_itemview', 
     'content_itemview', 
     'footer_itemview',
     'templates',
     'text_dictionary',
     'indexpage_model',
     'indexpage_logic'], 
    function( Page,
              Panel,
              Header,
              Content,
              Footer,
              Templates,
              Text_Dict,
              IndexPageModel,
              IndexPage_BusnLogic) {
console.log("Success..Inside Index Page.");
var Page_Index = {};
Page_Index.page = (function(){
    var _pageName = Text_Dict.indexpage_name;
    var _pageModel = new IndexPageModel();
    return _pageLayout = Page.pageLayout({
        name:_pageName,
        panelView:      Panel.panelView({name:_pageName, pagetemplate: Templates.simple_panel}),
        headerView:     Header.headerView({name:_pageName, title: Text_Dict.indexpage_header, pagetemplate: Templates.header_with_buttons}),
        contentView:    Content.contentView({name:_pageName, page_model:_pageModel, pagetemplate:Templates.content_index, busn_logic:IndexPage_BusnLogic.HandleEvents}),
        footerView:     Footer.footerView({name:_pageName, title: Text_Dict.indexpage_footer, pagetemplate: Templates.simple_footer})
    });
})();

return Page_Index;
});
```

my page gets created using the page layout

```
define([ 'underscore', 'marionette' ], function( _, Marionette ) {
console.log("Success..Inside Index View.");
var Page = {};
var _ReplaceWithRegion = Marionette.Region.extend({
     open: function(view){
        //Need this to keep Panel/Header/Content/Footer at the same level for panel to work properly
        this.$el.replaceWith(view.el);
    }
});
Page.pageLayout = function (opts) {
    var _opts = _.extend ({ name: 'noname',
                            panelView: null,
                            headerView: null,
                            contentView: null, 
                            footerView: null,                               
                            }, opts);
    return new ( Marionette.Layout.extend({
        tagName: 'section', 
        attributes: function() {
            return {
                'id':           'page_' + _opts.name,
                'data-url':     'page_' + _opts.name,
                'data-role':    'page',
                'data-theme':   'a'
            };
        },
        template: function () { 
            return "<div region_id='panel'/><div region_id='header'/><div region_id='content'/><div region_id='footer'/>";
        },
        regions: {
          panel:    {selector: "[region_id=panel]",     regionType: _ReplaceWithRegion},
          header:   {selector: "[region_id=header]",    regionType: _ReplaceWithRegion},
          content:  {selector: "[region_id=content]",   regionType: _ReplaceWithRegion},
          footer:   {selector: "[region_id=footer]",    regionType: _ReplaceWithRegion},
        },

        initialize: function(){
            $('body').append(this.$el);
            this.render();
        },              
        onRender: function() {
            if (this.options.panelView) {
                this.panel.show (this.options.panelView);
            };
            if (this.options.headerView) {
                this.header.show (this.options.headerView);
            };
            if (this.options.contentView) {
                this.content.show(this.options.contentView);
            };
            if (this.options.footerView) {
                this.footer.show (this.options.footerView);
            };
        },
    }))(_opts);
};
return Page;
});
```

but in my itemview when i am passing model reference like this

```
define([ 'underscore', 'marionette', 'event_dictionary', 'app' ], function(_, 
    Marionette, Event_Dict, App) {
console.log("Success..Inside Content Index View.");
var Content = {};
Content.contentView = function(opts) {
    return new (Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName : 'div',
        attributes : function() {
            console.log('options name==' + opts.name);
            console.log("page model=="+opts.page_model);
            return {
                'region_id' : 'content',
                'id' : 'content_' + opts.name,
                'data-role' : 'content'
            };
        },
        initialize : function() {
            _.bindAll(this, "template");
        },
        template : function() {
            return opts.pagetemplate;
        },
        model : function() {
            return opts.page_model;
        }
    }))(opts);
};
return Content;
});
```

It's giving me error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
            return opts.page_model;
        } has no method 'toJSON'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the line(s) of code where you instantiate your view? Also can you please provide information on what opts.page_model is referencing?

Comment: Actually i am using a very different way to create a page, can you please refer code from my github repo.. its over here [link](https://github.com/rachnakhokhar/VIBE_JRM_Framework.git) @dcarson

Comment: It would be great if you could just post the relevant bits in the question instead of us having to look through your code :) However the problem is probably that you are passing a function as a model and not an object literal.

Comment: Hello @dcarson i have updated my code please check.

Comment: Peter Lyons confirms my suspicions stated in my comment above, its the fact you are passing a function as a model. His code sample should work fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `model` property of a view cannot be a function. Backbone allows this for some things like `url` (by way of the `_.result` helper function), but not in this case. Change your view code to not have a `model` function and just do this in `initialize`:

```
initialize: function (options) {
    this.model = this.page_model = options.page_model;
}
```

**UPDATE** since you won't just take my word for it, [here is the Marionette source](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.itemview.js#L19) that is almost certainly the top of your exception stack trace. Once again: `view.model` has to be a model object not a function. Fix that and the error will go away.

Comment: Hello @Peter Lyons thanks for the reply. But earlier i was using the model property as a function and it was working perfectly. Can you please see my complete code above I have edited my question, and provide me with you valuable answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, you are simply incorrect about `view.model` being a function and working OK. Read the link to the Marionette source code I updated in my answer to be sure.

Comment: just do `model: opts.page_model` ?

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply everyone. And sorry @PeterLyons for not trusting you. But after doing `model: opts.page_model` that error got solved but a new came which is **uncaught reference error:val_btn_gotohomepage** which I have declared in my model as well as the template in which i am using it. Can you please advice what should I do now.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but it took a bit of messing about to find out why I had that error coming up, so I'm offering what the solution for my personal use-case was in case it helps anyone else stumbling upon this page in the future.

I had this:

```
app.module 'Widget.Meta', (Meta, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Meta.metaView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    model: app.Entities.Models.meta
    template: '#meta-template'
```

... when I should have had this:

```
app.module 'Widget.Meta', (Meta, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Meta.metaView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    model: new app.Entities.Models.meta()
    template: '#meta-template'
```

It's just a matter of *instantiating* the *function definition*.